# ls showing "no such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Could someone please explain this to me?

```
[rabdelaz@Linux_Desktop:/etc/apache2]$sudo ls /var/log/apache2/*.log
ls: cannot access /var/log/apache2/*.log: No such file or directory

[rabdelaz@Linux_Desktop:/etc/apache2]$sudo ls /var/log/apache2/
access.log  error.log.1      error.log.11.gz  error.log.13.gz  error.log.2.gz  error.log.4.gz  error.log.6.gz  error.log.8.gz  other_vhosts_access.log
error.log   error.log.10.gz  error.log.12.gz  error.log.14.gz  error.log.3.gz  error.log.5.gz  error.log.7.gz  error.log.9.gz  ssl_access.log
```

Clearly there IS such file or directory. I am confused. Is Ubuntu also confused?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shell will try try expand the `*`  wildcard, before elevating the privileges of the `ls` command.
Because as a regular user you don't have sufficient rights to read `/var/log/apache2` that expansion will fail.

Then the `*.log` will be passed through to `sudo`, but since `sudo` doesn't do globbing (that's a shell function) the `ls` will fail again as there is no file named `*.log`

A circumvention would be:

```
sudo sh -c 'ls /var/log/apache2/*.log'
```